# xaml windows phone 8.1 combobox Preselection display

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a comboBox that contains cars objects like the following:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="carsCombo" Grid.Column="1" >
                            <ComboBoxItem>Benz</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>BMW</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>VW</ComboBoxItem>

                        </ComboBox>
```

when the page is loaded, I don't set any selection in the code so no car is selected.. However the initial display of the comboBox will put a lable saying: "choose an item"

I want to change that string to : " choose a car" or whatever instruction i want to give the user.

I tried many properties of the comboBox but I failed.

I don't like the solution of adding and empty item and then selecting it. Because I think I can change this sentence in XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the property PlaceholderText directly in XAML.

Answer (score -1):

you can set the property "IsSelected" of one of your item to true.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @igor answered it already, what i was missing is placeholderText property